# Why does the Jinja2 template throw jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound error even though file is there?

Tags: python, templates, django-templates, jinja2

I'm struggling with the Jinja2 templating system. Even though the error path is pointing **exactly** to the .jinja2 file it is throwing template not found error.

Here is the current structure of folder.

```
❯ tree
.
├── generate_template.py
└── templates
    ├── kustomization.jinja2
    ├── pwa.jinja2
    └── shopware.jinja2
```

Here is content of generate_template.py

```py
import jinja2
import os

# Define instance values
values = {
    "instance_name": "test",
    "instance_currency": "usd",
    "instance_locale": "en-us",
    "patch": "2023.06.01",
}


# Create Jinja2 environment with the loader
template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "templates")
loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader('templates')
env = jinja2.Environment(loader=loader)

# Iterate over template files in the template directory

for template_name in os.listdir(template_dir):
    template_path = os.path.join(template_dir, template_name)
    template = env.get_template(template_path)
    # Render the template with values and write to file
    file_path = os.path.join(template_dir, template_name[:-7] + ".yaml") # Remove the .jinja2 extension and add .yaml
    with open(file_path, "w", encoding="utf8") as f:
        f.write(template.render(values))
```

Still, when I'm trying to execute the script I'm getting template not found error even though it is pointing exactly to the template.

```bash
❯ python3 generate_template.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/oskar/Desktop/test/generate_template.py", line 22, in <module>
    template = env.get_template(template_path)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1010, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, globals)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 969, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, self.make_globals(globals))
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 126, in load
    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 218, in get_source
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: /Users/oskar/Desktop/test/templates/kustomization.jinja2
```

I tried to use absolute path instead of relative, debugging it, printing paths - nothing helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jinja will automatically read the file from the templates folder, you don't need to specify the full path (see https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/).

Changing the line `template = env.get_template(template_path)` to `template = env.get_template(template_name)` should be enough.